# What does the global in (function(global){ some code .. })(this) do?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at adding comments to JSON and found [this script](https://github.com/getify/JSON.minify/blob/master/minify.json.js) that strips them out before processing making the JSON valid.  I am just trying to understand how it works to make the JSON.minify() function available?

It starts with

```
(function(global){ ...
```

totally which is weird to me.  I found that "[global is a property of a RegExp instance, not the RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)" on MDN but I don't understand how it is works in this script if at all.

Comment: The function is invoked in the global context. Therefore, the `this` argument is the global object which is assigned to the `global` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet:

```
(function(global){
   // your code here
   // referring to the variable named "global" in this scope 
   // will be a reference to the default javascript global object
})(this);
```

is a construct for assigning the global object (whatever it might be) to an argument labeled `global` for all code that is inside this self-executing function.

The self executing function is used to define a separate execution scope so that any functions or variables you define inside this other scope will not interfere with or be directly accessible from outside this scope (insulating your scope from other code scopes).

In a browser, the global object is the `window` object, but if you intended to have code that might work in other javascript environments (like no node.js on a server) where the global object might not be `window`, this is a way of extracting the global value from the default `this` value, putting it into another variable which you can then refer to anywhere inside your code block.

For code mean to only run in a browser, there really is no point to this.  You can just refer to `window` when you need the global object.

Comment: Even if running only in a browser, there can still be a point.  You can save some bytes in minification since the `global` parameter will likely be one character; saving 5 bytes for each time you'd reference `window`.

Comment: @josh3736 - I guess you're right about minification.  I generally prioritize readability to someone who hasn't seen my code before above minification so I don't generally partake of things like this purely for the sake of minification.  But, yes that's a personal choice.

Comment: If it's browser-only, just name the parameter `window` (instead of `global`).  That way you'll get the minification benefits, but retain readability -- you can still write `window.location` or whatever.  In fact, that's how jQuery [does it](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) -- `(function(window, undefined) { ... })(window);`

Answer (score 2):

It's just a function parameter name. It might as well be `froozboggles`.

This code:

```
(function(foo) {
    // In here, what's called "bar" in the outer scope is called "foo"
})(bar);
```

Defines an anonymous function taking one parameter `bar` and immediately calls it with the value of `bar` as the first parameter.

Apart from what jfriend00 mentions in his fine answer, it's also a good way of making sure that you don't leak variables and functions to the outer scope: If you declare, say, `var baz = 17;` in the top scope in javascript, it will be a property of `window`. If you wrap it in a function as in the pattern you mention, you can only export properties to `window` explicitly -- by assigning them to `global`, in the case of your example. **Edit:** As @josh3736 says in his comment, you can also leak to `window` by assigning without a previous declaration, e.g. `quux = 4711;`.

Comment: +1 for making up a unique word. zero google hits for froozboggles.

Comment: *"You can only export properties to window explicitly"* -- this isn't exactly true.  A plain `baz = ...;` will assign to the global object (`window`) if there is no `baz` otherwise in scope.  In other words, `(function(global) { baz=''; })(this)` still leaks `baz` even though it wasn't *explicitly* assigned to `window`.